# Listing people with their phone numbers (if any)

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables in my database:

```
people:          phones:
+----+------+    +-----------+------------+-------------+
| id | name |    | person_id | number     | description |
+----+------+    +-----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Jade |    |         1 | 1234567890 | home        |
|  2 | Ben  |    |         1 |  987654321 | office      |
+----+------+    +-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I use a query with `INNER JOIN` to select the name and phone numbers for each person:

```
SELECT
   id,
   name, 
   group_concat(
      concat(
         number,
         ' (',
         description,
         ')'
      ) ORDER BY description SEPARATOR ','
   ) AS phones
FROM people INNER JOIN phones
ON person_id = id
GROUP BY id;
```

Results from the above query:

```
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
| id | name | phones                               |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | Jade | 1234567890 (home),987654321 (office) |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
```

But I want to use this query to go through all the people in my database and not just the ones with phone numbers, so I added the following row to the phones table:

```
INSERT INTO phones VALUES (0, 0, NULL);
```

And then modified the `ON` statement of the query to:

```
ON person_id = id OR person_id = 0
```

That way every person gets selected even if he has no phone numbers registered in the database:

```
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
| id | name | phones                               |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | Jade | 1234567890 (home),987654321 (office) |
|  2 | Ben  | NULL                                 |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+
```

Is this a proper way to achieve this? I don't really like the idea of having to make sure that the `0, 0, NULL` row will always stay in the database in order to ensure the queries will work as intended. (since the company I develop this for might decide to clear the database)

This implementation requires calling an `ensureNullRow()` function every time before using this query, is this a good solution or would you do it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is known as`LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
   id,
   name, 
   group_concat(
      concat(
         number,
         ' (',
         description,
         ')'
      ) ORDER BY description SEPARATOR ','
   ) AS phones
FROM people LEFT OUTER JOIN phones
ON person_id = id
GROUP BY id;
```

`inner join` => give me only rows with records in both tables
`left outer join` => give me all rows of from the left table along with any matching rows in the right..